# Error importing CSS file in fixed data table 2

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm using fixed data table-2(0.8.13) along with React(15.4.2).
However when I import the CSS file, I am getting an error

> Module parse failed:
>   /Users/Desktop/ReactReduxStore/node_modules/fixed-data-table-2/dist/fixed-data-table.css
>   Unexpected token (23:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type.

I'm importing it as follows:

```
import 'fixed-data-table-2/dist/fixed-data-table.css';
```

Comment: Add your `webpack.config.js` code.

Comment: // webpack.config.js

`module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 3000
    }
};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gotta add `css` loaders to import them,

add `css-loader` and `style-loader`:

```
npm install --save-dev css-loader style-loader
```

then in `webpack.config.js` do as following:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      { 
        loader: 'babel-loader', 
         test: /\.js$/, 
         exclude: /node_modules/ 
      },{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
}
```

**Note that:**

> `module.loaders` in Webpack v1 is now `module.rules` in Webpack v2+.
>   The old loader configuration was superseded by a more powerful rules system, which allows configuration of loaders and more. For compatibility reasons, the old module.loaders syntax is still valid and the old names are parsed. The new naming conventions are easier to understand and are a good reason to upgrade the configuration to using module.rules.